# Restricted shell is not working for a newly created user (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: bash, permissions, ssh, restricted

I want to create a new user with a restricted shell so I :

```
ln -s bash rbash  # create a symbolic link to bash with a name "rbash" 

useradd -s /bin/rbash student # add a new user with a shell pointing to that symlink I've created

passwd student # create a password 

su - student # Login as a user
```

However afterwards I can cd into wherever I want. 
It looks like a restricted shell doesn't work. 
Why ?

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like `echo $0` says `-su` in this context; whereas if one does `ssh student@localhost` then `echo $0` says `-rbash` and it works as expected...

Comment: @steeldriver just checked it and yes you are right. What the hell ? :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `man bash`, the restricted shell is mentioned as follows:

> ```
>    If bash is started with the name rbash, or the -r option is supplied at
>    invocation, the shell becomes restricted.
> ```

However, it looks like the version of `su` in Ubuntu 18.04 replaces the name of the shell with `su`; so when bash looks at its `argv[0]` it sees `su` (or `-su` in the case that `su` was invoked with one of the `-`, `-l` or `--login` options) instead of `rbash` (or `-rbash`).

You can actually change this behavior by editing the `/etc/login.defs` file and commenting out the `SU_NAME` setting:

```
# If defined, the command name to display when running "su -".  For
# example, if this is defined as "su" then a "ps" will display the
# command is "-su".  If not defined, then "ps" would display the
# name of the shell actually being run, e.g. something like "-sh".
#
# SU_NAME               su
```

**Whether this is a good idea, or may have other unintended consequences, I can't say.** Note that newer versions of Ubuntu likely use a different implementation of `/bin/su` (from the `util-linux` package) which may not exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Interesting, pls what newer versions are we talking here?

Comment: @steeldriver thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Tomas.R I don't know for sure when the changeover happened (and the Ubuntu launchpad changelogs aren't helpful); however if you search the packages.ubuntu.com it appears that Eoan is the first release in which `/bin/su` appears in the fileslist of package util-linux